# JavaScript key event to Linux keycode

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux

Is it possible to map a JavaScript key event to the keycode output you receive from linux' `showkey`?

My idea so far: Ask the client to specify the keyboard layout used. Than "somehow" map the events according to the layout set. It could be possible to query the mapping from the server that is definitely running on Linux so the keyboard layout mappings must be somewhere in the OS. (Note that node can interact with c/c++).

Here is my use case: I'm building a nodejs server that serves a virtual keyboard. It is sending the key events to `uinput`. I have it working with clicking on a keyboard SVG because I known which key has which keycode on Linux. Now I want to support the clients hardware keyboard. You can find the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/roba91/node-virtual-gamepads/tree/virtual_keyboard).

Comment: What is `showkey`?

Comment: A Linux program that examine the codes sent by the keyboard. Find more here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/showkey.1.html or here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/extra_keyboard_keys#Using_showkey